# Stored procedure or SQL to execute 1-2 times daily - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, decode, dbms-scheduler

I am rendering a report using a single huge oracle table having an emoji column (with possible values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). I am doing a live count(*) and percentage count per emoji for every report query currently. I have the option to generate the report for 7 days, 30 days, 60 days and 90 days.

My ask:
- Run a stored proc/SQL to store the counts and percentage counts per emoji in a separate table 1-2 times daily.
- Insert if new, update it existing. There will be 4 records inserted/updated per day, one each for frequency 7, 30, 60 and 90 days.
- Run this via a scheduler at 6 am and/or 6 pm daily.

My schema

```
desc reports;

MESSAGE_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
USER_ID    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)  
EMOJI      NOT NULL NUMBER(2)     
MESSAGE             VARCHAR2(140) 
TS_CREATE  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(0)  
TS_UPDATE  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(0)
```

My current query from java program for 30 day and 60 day frequency:

```
select emoji, COUNT(1) Total_emoji_count, 
ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100,2) Total_emoji_percent
FROM reports where ts_create > sysdate - 30 GROUP BY emoji ORDER BY emoji;

select emoji, COUNT(1) Total_emoji_count, 
ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100,2) Total_emoji_percent
FROM reports where ts_create > sysdate - 60 GROUP BY emoji ORDER BY emoji;
```

This returns :
[image]

However, I would like to have the rows displayed as columns for easy readability. Something like this inserted everyday.

[image]

I have tried the following SQL, I can get the counts but am unable to get the percentage(s) working. Any pointers?

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(emoji, 1, count(1), 0)) "e1_count",
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 2, count(1), 0)) "e2_count",  
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 3, count(1), 0)) "e3_count",  
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 4, count(1), 0)) "e4_count",  
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 5, count(1), 0)) "e5_count"
FROM  reports where ts_create > trunc(sysdate) - 30
GROUP BY emoji ORDER BY emoji;
```

EDIT -- New variant

```
emoji_FREQ as (
select
trunc(sysdate),
f.FREQUENCY,
m.emoji,
COUNT(1) e_count,
RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100 e_percent
FROM reports m, FREQUENCY_TBL f
where m.ts_create > trunc(sysdate) - f.FREQUENCY
GROUP BY FREQUENCY, emoji
) SELECT
trunc(sysdate),
FREQUENCY,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 1, e_count, 0)) e1_count,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 2, e_count, 0)) e2_count,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 3, e_count, 0)) e3_count,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 4, e_count, 0)) e4_count,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 5, e_count, 0)) e5_count,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 1, e_percent, 0)) e1_percent,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 2, e_percent, 0)) e2_percent,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 3, e_percent, 0)) e3_percent,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 4, e_percent, 0)) e4_percent,
SUM(DECODE(emoji, 5, e_percent, 0)) e5_percent
FROM emoji_FREQ
GROUP BY FREQUENCY;
```

Comment: Are you looking for [PIVOT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE)?

Comment: Yes, PIVOT is fine, if simple DECODE is not possible. I will use this 'select' to insert 3 rows into another table later.

Answer (score 0):

you ca either use a PIVOT query (https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php)  or try something like this

```
SELECT log_message_date, 
       30 AS frequency, 
       e1_count, 
       Round(e1_count/total*100), 
       e2_count, 
       Round(e2_count/total*100), 
       e3_count, 
       Round(e3_count/total*100), 
       e4_count, 
       Round(e4_count/total*100), 
       e5_count, 
       Round(e5_count/total*100) 
FROM  ( 
                SELECT   SUM(Decode(emoji, 
                                    1, Count(1), 
                                    0)) "e1_count", 
                         SUM(Decode(emoji, 
                                    2, Count(1), 
                                    0)) "e2_count", 
                         SUM(Decode(emoji, 
                                    3, Count(1), 
                                    0)) "e3_count", 
                         SUM(Decode(emoji, 
                                    4, Count(1), 
                                    0)) "e4_count", 
                         SUM(Decode(emoji, 
                                    5, Count(1), 
                                    0)) "e5_count",
                         count(emoji) AS total, 
                         trunc(ts_create)                       AS log_message_date 
                FROM     reports 
                WHERE    ts_create > trunc(SYSDATE) - 30 
                GROUP BY trunc(ts_create))
```

Comment: I'm getting a ORA-00904: "E5_COUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" for line "Round(e5_count/total*100)"

Comment: I also tried a slightly different variant after creating a new table FREQUENCY_TBL with field named FREQUENCY records with values 7, 30, 60, 90....I was able to get the counts working but the percentages still isn't right....Editing original post with new query

Comment: sorry a , is missing

Comment: thanks but it is still  failing : ORA-00904: "E5_COUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 14  for Round(e5_count/total*100) line